# SQL Server 2000 - ALTER TABLE + INSERT INTO = Errors?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to alter a table to add a new column, then insert a new row into it.

```
ALTER TABLE Roles ADD ModifiedDate DateTime;
INSERT INTO Roles (Name, [Description], CreatedBy, BuiltIn, Created, ModifiedDate)
    VALUES ('Name', 'Description', 0, 1, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
```

but I get:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ModifiedDate'.
```

when i try to run the above SQL in SQL Server Management Studio. I think this is a Studio error, not a server error. If the SQL was run, it should work as the column would exist at that point.

How can I add a new column to a table and then insert into that table?

Versions:

- SQL Server 2000
- SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As expected. SQL Server does not execute line by line. It compiles and parse the batch, and when this happens the column does not exist.

You need to decouple the 2 actions thus

```
ALTER TABLE Roles ADD ModifiedDate DateTime;
EXEC ('
    INSERT INTO Roles (Name, [Description], CreatedBy, BuiltIn, Created, ModifiedDate)
    VALUES (''Name'', ''Description'', 0, 1, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
')
```

A "GO" is a batch separator only for client tools and is not recognised by the server

Comment: Is there a way to turn off this batching? I have this issue about 20 -30 items in my SQL file. its updating a database from one version to another.

Comment: @Justin808: Not without dynamic SQL or GO. It's how SQL Server creates execution plans and is fundamental to how it works. It isn't procedural/line by line.

Comment: That seems like a massive drawback to me. I would expect items being done higher in the file to be done when items lower in the file are hit. How can I use GO in the middle of an IF block, and how can I use it without resetting all my variables?

Comment: Or if I shouldn't use GO, much I wrap each statement in a EXEC to make sure its all run in the right order at the expected time?

Comment: @Justin808: SQL is declarative, not procedural. It isn't a command line script or an exectuable. You have to recode to use GO or use EXEC

Answer (score 0):

What about transations?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE Roles ADD ModifiedDate DateTime;
GO;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Roles (Name, [Description], CreatedBy, BuiltIn, Created, ModifiedDate) VALUES ('Name', 'Description', 0, 1, GETDATE(), GETDATE());
GO;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```