# TSQL - How to use GO inside of a BEGIN .. END block?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am generating a script for automatically migrating changes from multiple development databases to staging/production.  Basically, it takes a bunch of change-scripts, and merges them into a single script, wrapping each script in a `IF whatever BEGIN ... END` statement.

However, some of the scripts require a `GO` statement so that, for instance, the SQL parser knows about a new column after it's created.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE 
ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL
GO -- Necessary, or next line will generate "Unknown column:  EMP_IS_ADMIN"
UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = whatever
```

However, once I wrap that in an `IF` block:

```
IF whatever
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL
    GO
    UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = whatever
END
```

It fails because I am sending a `BEGIN` with no matching `END`.  However, if I remove the `GO` it complains again about an unknown column.

**Is there any way to create and update the same column within a single `IF` block?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855537/sql-server-2000-alter-table-insert-into-errors/4855582#4855582 please

Comment: @gbn: Yes, I realize why this happens *(see second paragraph)*; but I have no idea how to work around it - do I *really* need to turn every query into a bunch of strings!?

Comment: @BlueRaja: What's the concern?  If it works, that's all that matters at the end of the day.  If there's a legitimate business problem with the solution provided, please express that.  Is there something specifically disconcerting about converting every query into a bunch of strings?

Comment: @mellamokb: Yes, there's a problem; if the word GO is used in any other context (such as a comment, or a string), the script won't work.  Also, we lose the useful line-numbers in error messages in case anything goes wrong.  Is there no way to do this with transactions? Or try/catch?

Comment: @BlueRaja: 1) I believe `GO` has to be on a line by itself, so you can search for that case only, and not every instance of the word `GO`.  2) You can always log which statements were completed successfully.  Or you could wrap the whole thing in a try/catch and use your own line numbers using some variable, like @lineNo, that you keep track of, and report out on error.  Since you are generating these automatically, making changes like this should be a breeze.  It just sounds like you plain don't want to explore this route when I think there are solutions to be found for all of your concerns.

Comment: @BlueRaja: See my updated answer to get an example of what I mean.  You can run the script and it will error on the third statement, which should show in the error output that it was line 2 of statement 3.  You could just as easily log the output to a table or whatever works best in your script automation.  Please let me know if this helps at all, I want to help you find a solution that works for you :-)

Comment: @BlueRaja: Even with a try/catch or transaction (which I would definitely recommend anyway, see how I have incorporated both into my answer), the problem you will always have is that the entire script is parsed, compiled and validated before it is ever run, so it will always complain about the missing column instead of running the script.  You either have to run the script as strings or run the scripts separately and individually.

Comment: When updating an existing table with a new non-nullable column, this is the canonical way to accomplish that.  Test whether the column already exists, if not, create the new column as nullable, set a default value for all rows, ALTER the new column definition to NOT NULL.  It is simply inexcusable that such a standard task should be so difficult. </rant>

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally managed to solve it using **[SET NOEXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql)**.

```
IF not whatever
BEGIN
    SET NOEXEC ON; 
END

ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL
GO
UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = whatever

SET NOEXEC OFF;
```

Comment: This is a great solution!

Comment: +1!  This is the ONLY *practical* Answer so far for use in a SS `SQLCMD` Mode Script (i.e. a master deployment script) that calls (via `:r` command) other SS Scripts (i.e. sub-deployment scripts) with some of those calls inside `if` Statements.  Oded's, mellamokb's and Andy Joiner's Answers of enclosing *all* those Statements in `exec` Calls / `begin`-`end`'s are non-starters.  Also, the `begin`-`end` method won't work if there's a `create` Statement (e.g. requires an explicit `go` prior to it).  But, man, "Holy double negatives, Batman!" ;)

Comment: For readability (e.g., to help overcome the double-negatives and make it clearer that it's simulating a *virtual* `if`-block), I would prefix the block with an `-- If whatever` Comment, indent the block and postfix the block with an `--end If whatever` Comment.

Comment: You saved my bacon! I was running merge statements and those dumb GO's don't like to be inside a IF BEGIN END ELSE

Comment: Hm, I'm getting an error on the update somehow after set noexec on has been executed? (error that the column name to update is invalid) Running on MSSQL 2014 in the query editor. Works fine if the condition turns false (thus noexec remains off)

Comment: For incrementive scripts, appropriate solution is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376909/3127815).

Consecutive runs of the script above would cast
`Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'EMP_IS_ADMIN' in table 'EMPLOYEE' is specified more than once.`

Answer (score 55):

[`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is not SQL - it is simply a batch separator used in some MS SQL tools.

If you don't use that, you need to ensure the statements are executed separately - either in different batches or by using dynamic SQL for the population (thanks @gbn):

```
IF whatever
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL;

    EXEC ('UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = whatever')
END
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  This does not answer the question - I need to create and update a column in the same `IF` block.

Comment: @Oded: Would the `;` help out here? - You've just edited your answer :o)

Comment: @Neil - this is my thinking, yes.

Comment: `;` doesn't work either - the parser is still giving me *"Invalid column name 'EMP_IS_ADMIN'."*

Comment: When the batch is compiled, EMP_IS_ADMIN does not exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855537/sql-server-2000-alter-table-insert-into-errors/4855582#4855582

Comment: Mina Jacob's `set noexec` Answer is the ONLY *practical* Answer so far for use in a SS `SQLCMD` Mode Script (i.e. a master deployment script) that calls (via `:r` command) other SS Scripts (i.e. sub-deployment scripts) with some of those calls inside `if` Statements.  Oded's, mellamokb's and Andy Joiner's Answers of enclosing *all* those Statements in `exec` Calls / `begin`-`end`'s are non-starters.  Also, the `begin`-`end` method won't work if there's a `create` Statement (e.g. requires an explicit `go` prior to it).

Answer (score 18):

You could try [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), splitting the contents between each `GO` statement into a separate string to be executed, as demonstrated in the example below.  Also, there is a @statementNo variable to track which statement is being executed for easy debugging where an exception occurred.   The line numbers will be relative to the beginning of the relevant statement number that caused the error.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @statementNo INT
BEGIN TRY
    IF 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @statementNo = 1
        EXEC sp_executesql
            N'  ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE
                    ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL'

        SET @statementNo = 2
        EXEC sp_executesql
            N'  UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE
                    SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = 1'

        SET @statementNo = 3
        EXEC sp_executesql
            N'  UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE
                    SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = 1x'
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error occurred on line ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(10)) 
       + ' of ' + 'statement # ' + cast(@statementNo as varchar(10)) 
       + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    -- error occurred, so rollback the transaction
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
-- if we were successful, we should still have a transaction, so commit it
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT
```

You can also easily execute multi-line statements, as demonstrated in the example above, by simply wrapping them in single quotes (`'`).  Don't forget to escape any single quotes contained inside the string with a double single-quote (`''`) when generating the scripts.

Comment: Don't think this would work for commands split across multiple lines, would it?

Comment: @BlueRaja: I have updated the example to show how it would work.  Those strings can be multi-line, as long as any single quotes (') contained inside are escaped by using a double-single quote ('')

Comment: @mellamokb: strictly speaking, only the UPDATE needs sp_executesql ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855537/sql-server-2000-alter-table-insert-into-errors/4855582#4855582

Comment: @gbn: True.  But if you're going to automate this for 100's of statements, it will be easier to just apply it blindly across all statements instead of deciding when and where you need it.

Comment: @gbn @mellamokb: I meant statements like `SELECT * <newline> FROM whatever`.  If I execute every line with its own EXEC statement, that will break.  Or are you suggesting I break at every `GO` statement?

Comment: @BlueRaja: Correct, that is the whole point.  I guess I didn't explain that, but I assumed you understood that I am putting each batch within a string, i.e., split around each `GO`.

Comment: Mina Jacob's `set noexec` Answer is the ONLY *practical* Answer so far for use in a SS `SQLCMD` Mode Script (i.e. a master deployment script) that calls (via `:r` command) other SS Scripts (i.e. sub-deployment scripts) with some of those calls inside `if` Statements.  Oded's, mellamokb's and Andy Joiner's Answers of enclosing *all* those Statements in `exec` Calls / `begin`-`end`'s are non-starters.  Also, the `begin`-`end` method won't work if there's a `create` Statement (e.g. requires an explicit `go` prior to it).

Answer (score 13):

You can enclose the statements in BEGIN and END instead of the GO inbetween

```
IF COL_LENGTH('Employees','EMP_IS_ADMIN') IS NULL --Column does not exist
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees ADD EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = 0
    END
END
```

(Tested on Northwind database)

Edit: (Probably tested on SQL2012)

Comment: Please give reason for -1

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted... works like a charm for me.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008 R2, this doesn't seem to work for me, I still get an error 'Invalid column name 'EMP_IS_ADMIN'.' on the UPDATE line.

Comment: The BEGIN-END batching worked for me using SQL Server 2016. IMO this is the cleanest syntax.

Comment: Mina Jacob's `set noexec` Answer is the ONLY *practical* Answer so far for use in a SS `SQLCMD` Mode Script (i.e. a master deployment script) that calls (via `:r` command) other SS Scripts (i.e. sub-deployment scripts) with some of those calls inside `if` Statements.  Oded's, mellamokb's and Andy Joiner's Answers of enclosing *all* those Statements in `exec` Calls / `begin`-`end`'s are non-starters.  Also, the `begin`-`end` method won't work if there's a `create` Statement (e.g. requires an explicit `go` prior to it).

Answer (score 9):

I ultimately got it to work by replacing every instance of `GO` on its own line with

```
END
GO

---Automatic replacement of GO keyword, need to recheck IF conditional:
IF whatever
BEGIN
```

This is greatly preferable to wrapping every group of statements in a string, but is still *far* from ideal.  If anyone finds a better solution, post it and I'll accept it instead.

Comment: If the first conditional is "if this column doesn't exist", the first statement in the block is "add this column", then the second check of the conditional will find the column and not execute the second statement,

Comment: @Damien: True; fortunately, that will never happen in my case (the conditional is always a check for a specific value in a specific table, which is always added as the last statement of the `IF` block).  It seems as though there is just no good way to do this in SQL.

Comment: Mina Jacob's `set noexec` Answer is the ONLY *practical* Answer so far for use in a SS `SQLCMD` Mode Script (i.e. a master deployment script) that calls (via `:r` command) other SS Scripts (i.e. sub-deployment scripts) with some of those calls inside `if` Statements.  Oded's, mellamokb's and Andy Joiner's Answers of enclosing *all* those Statements in `exec` Calls / `begin`-`end`'s are non-starters.  Also, the `begin`-`end` method won't work if there's a `create` Statement (e.g. requires an explicit `go` prior to it).

Answer (score 2):

You may try this solution:

```
if exists(
SELECT...
)
BEGIN
PRINT 'NOT RUN'
RETURN
END

--if upper code not true

ALTER...
GO
UPDATE...
GO
```

Comment: Not very useful if you have several if-else blocks one after the other, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `RAISERROR` in the past for this

```
IF NOT whatever BEGIN
    RAISERROR('YOU''RE ALL SET, and sorry for the error!', 20, -1) WITH LOG
END

ALTER TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN EMP_IS_ADMIN BIT NOT NULL
GO
UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE SET EMP_IS_ADMIN = whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

You can incorporate a `GOTO` and `LABEL` statements to skip over code, thus leaving the `GO` keywords intact.

Comment: It seems that LABELs cannot be referenced across GO statements since they are not in the batch sent to SQL