# Difference between EXEC('UPDATE') and UPDATE for a new column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I must add a *Not Nullable* column, but I don't have a known value for default so I create the column as *Nullable*, after that I update all rows and then change the column to be *Not Nullable*.

Running the following script finished with success.

```
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE driver ADD DriverLocationId INT NULL
    EXEC('UPDATE driver 
    SET DriverLocationId = (SELECT TOP(1) CountryId FROM Country WHERE CountryCode IN (''USA'',''CAN'', ''MEX''))')
    ALTER TABLE driver ALTER COLUMN DriverLocationId INT NOT NULL   
END
```

And the following is failing.

```
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE driver ADD DriverLocationId INT NULL
    UPDATE driver 
        SET DriverLocationId = (SELECT TOP(1) CountryId FROM Country WHERE CountryCode IN ('USA','CAN', 'MEX'))
    ALTER TABLE driver ALTER COLUMN DriverLocationId INT NOT NULL   
 END
```

Probably when the update script from 1st attempt is executed correctly after altering.

Do you have any explanation for this?

**EDIT:** I have updated my question. Sorry for the double quotes. That wasn't a problem. Here is something more complicated.

**EDIT:** The error is:

> Invalid column name 'DriverLocationId'.

**EDIT (for @Stephan):** GO isn't working there [image: GO isn't working]

Comment: If you provided the actual error message for the second one, the problem would be more obvious. SQL Server is failing to *compile* all of the code, so none of the code ever executes. That's why you need the `UPDATE` that talks about the new column to be in a separate batch (so that when it compiles, the column exists)

Comment: I understand. Please post this as an answer or mark as duplicate. Thanks a lot Damien.

Comment: The problem are the command go, it is ending your transaction. try with out it

Comment: @MelgoV absolutely not.  GO is a batch separator in SQL server, that's all.  it doesn't end or terminate a transaction.

Comment: Please just try this: Begin

 print 'ok'
 Go

End

Comment: @MelgoV it didn't works bro'. GO isn't suitable to exist like this between begin and end. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376866/tsql-how-to-use-go-inside-of-a-begin-end-block

Comment: @MelgoV - `BEGIN ... END` are not transaction related. Transactions are controlled by `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and either `ROLLBACK [TRANSACTION]` or `COMMIT [TRANSACTION]` - so whilst you may have a valid point about the control structure being broken up, it's got nothing to do with transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Remove the extra single quotes for ''USA'' and use 'USA' instead. The same for the other values of course.

And then, as i said into my comment: In the second case SQL does not yet see that the column has been added. The mentioned GO statement would make that work, but does not work in this code because it is between the BEGIN and END tags. I believe that EXEC executes the statement in a new session and therefore is not hindered by this problem.

Comment: The string opens at 'UPDATE...  What your suggesting will close the string at ...WHERE ContryCode IN ('

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for the double quotes. That wasn't a problem. Here is something more complicated.

Comment: In the second case SQL does not yet see that the column has been added. The mentioned GO statement would make that work, but does not work in this code because it is between the BEGIN and END tags. I believe that EXEC executes the statement in a new session and therefore is not hindered by this problem.