# Error when adding a new column and change the value in the same SQL script

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

In one SQL script (SQL Server 2016) I want to add a column by using `ALTER TABLE` and change the values by using `UPDATE`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns  
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable') and NAME = 'MyAttribute')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MyTable 
        ADD MyAttribute BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0);

    UPDATE MyTable 
    SET MyAttribute = 1;
END
```

but I get an error

> Invalid column name 'MyAttribute'

for line 5 (the `update` statement).

The background for the code is:

- The script is running every time a new program version for the database is installed (I can't change this behaviour)
- `MyAttribute` should only be added at the first time of script execution
- The value for all **existing** records should be 1, but the default value for all new records must be 0

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376866/tsql-how-to-use-go-inside-of-a-begin-end-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to run in different batches:

```
declare @new bit = 0;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns  
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable') and NAME = 'MyAttribute')
BEGIN
    set @new = 1;
    ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyAttribute BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0);

END
Go
if @new = 1
begin
    UPDATE MyTable SET MyAttribute = 1;
end
```

EDIT:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns  
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable') and NAME = 'MyAttribute')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MyTable 
        ADD MyAttribute BIT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT df_attr DEFAULT(1);
    ALTER TABLE MyTable
        DROP CONSTRAINT df_attr; 
    ALTER TABLE MyTable
        ADD CONSTRAINT df_attr DEFAULT 0 FOR MyAttribute; 
END
```

Comment: This version with the "@new" -Flag unfortunately doesn't work, because the variable "new" isn't valid after the "Go". I've got the error:  Must declare the scalar variable "@new".

Comment: @Juergen2018, you are right. Then my first reaction was to add it as an EXEC sp_executesql inside the block, but that doesn't work either. I came up with the solution in the edited version, which does work.

Comment: your edited version works fine, thanks a lot for the solution!!