# SQL Dropping database with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, conditional-statements, drop

I'm working on some scripts for my Studies to create and Drop a Database.

For dropping the DB, I'd like to check if the Database exists or not - but I get an error message when using the IF condition together with "GO". This is what I intend to do:

```
If(db_id(N'Testdatabase') IS NOT NULL)
Begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'Testdatabase'
GO
use [Testdatabase];
GO
use [master];
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Testdatabase] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [Testdatabase]
GO
END
```

I tried following the link here, which describes the usage of "SET NOEXEC ON;", But I'm not able to get this to work. [TSQL - How to use GO inside of a BEGIN .. END block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376866/tsql-how-to-use-go-inside-of-a-begin-end-block)

Does anybody have an idea how I could reach my goal? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should add a tag for the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Thanks for the input - I added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code without GO:

```
If(db_id(N'Testdatabase') IS NOT NULL)
Begin

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name ='Testdatabase'
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE [Testdatabase] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
USE [master]
DROP DATABASE [Testdatabase]  
END
```